# got error on mass edit magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, massaction

On mass edit action i got these error. what i miss there?

**view/adminhtml/ui_component/test_test_listing.xml**

```
<action name="edit">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                        <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_index_listing.test_index_listing.test_index_columns_editor</item>
                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">editSelected</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
```

**Error**

```
editor.js (line 532, col 20)
TypeError: this.selections(...) is undefined


return this.selections().getPageSelections();
```

Comment: your xml file name is listing.xml or any other name?

Comment: it is in `view/adminhtml/ui_component/test_test_listing.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with these two lines

```
 <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_test_columns.test_test_columns.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
 <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_test_columns.test_test_columns.news_index_columns.ids</item>
```

**solution**

```
<columns name="news_index_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_test_listing.test_test_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_test_listing.test_test_listing.news_index_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="news/index/inlineEdit"/>
                        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
              </item>
        </argument>
    </columns>
```

Answer (score 1):

keep below code and remove var, try again,

```
<action name="edit">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                            <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_test_listing.test_test_listing.test_index_columns_editor</item>
                                <item name="target" xsi:type="string">editSelected</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </action>
```

Comment: thanks but i got the solution.

Comment: whats the issue?

Comment: i was using `test_test_columns` in the place on `test_test_listing`